# Connecting to Windows 8.1 phone from Linux Ubuntu

Tags: sync, linux

I am trying to connect to a Lumia 435 Windows 8.1 phone from Ubuntu.

It is an mtp device, and when I connect it to the computer, it gets mounted on Nautilus. I am even able to create directories in the phone and move files into these directories, which are visible from the phone. However, I can't read files that were previously there, or files that I copied into it in a previous session.

What's wrong here?

UPDATE: in the meantime I installed an FTP server app on the phone, and I am having no problem anymore transferring files in both directions. Accessing the phone directly would still be interesting, but not essential, at least for me.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @KolappanNathan it's 15.10